# Is it possible to merge branch again after hard reset on master?

Tags: git, github, merge

Here is my situation. I master a master branch, dev1 and dev2 branch. Now i've fast-forward dev1 into master. After that, I merge dev2 into master as well.

Now, the fast-forward merge is actually accidental as I wanted to put n a commit message.

Now I know I can hard reset using `git reset -- hard <hash of commit before any merge>` and then force push to master to rewrite history.

My question is that after i done all this, can i still normal merge dev1 and dev2 branch into master again with a custom special commit?

And will there be any problem as later, master will be merged into dev1 again as a copy of master where I can make new changes?

Comment: That should be fine, so long as no-one else has a copy of the repo with the changes you want to undo/redo. However, if you just want to add a message, can't you just tag the existing fast-forward merge instead?

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this one is, as for all history modifications, "it depends".  The [comment from Useless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36738228/is-it-possible-to-merge-branch-again-after-hard-reset-on-master#comment61058964_36738228) contains the right question: does anyone else have this yet?

In this particular case, though, the "this" part—the thing we're concerned that someone else might have—may actually be much less important (albeit still slightly important) than in other force-push cases.  The reason is that a fast-forward merge is not a merge at all, but rather just a label motion.

#### Draw the graphs

Let's draw the commit graphs.  Whenever we have a difficult case in git, "draw the commit graph" is almost always the right first step.

> I master *[I think this means "made" or "had"...?]* a master branch, dev1 and dev2 branch.

So:

```
... - o - o           <-- master
           \
            o - o     <-- dev1
                 \
                  o   <-- dev2
```

I am guessing somewhat here on how many commit nodes and whether this is a good shape to use.  It would help a lot if *you* draw the graph since you actually have the repository and can therefore draw a correct one.  But anyway:

> Now i've fast-forward dev1 into master.

I am guessing that by this you mean you did:

```
$ git checkout master && git merge dev1
```

and git told you that it did a fast-forward.  If that's true, there must not have been any commits on `master` that were not also on `dev1`, so at least part of my drawing must be right.  Here's the result:

```
... - o - o
           \
            o - o     <-- dev1, HEAD->master
                 \
                  o   <-- dev2
```

That is, both `dev1` and `master` are pointing to the *same* commit (hash `2199c3a...` or whatever).  I added `HEAD->` in front of `master` because we are on branch master (via `git checkout master`).

(We could re-draw the graph without the little dogleg in it, but let's just leave it going down and right even though there's no label on the first row any more.)

> After that, I merge dev2 into master as well.

You do not say whether this was also a fast-forward operation.  If you used no flags and the above graph is right (or close enough), it would be, and the result would be:

```
... - o - o
           \
            o - o     <-- dev1
                 \
                  o   <-- dev2, HEAD->master
```

In other words, each of these fast-forward operations—which are not merges at all—have simply slid the `master` label forward (hence the name "fast-forward").

Now we get to the question of whether you have pushed any of this.

If you have not pushed anything, you are in good shape, because *your repository is the only one with any changes*.

If you *have* pushed it, let's see what new commits you pushed.  Which commit nodes are in the final graph that were not in the original graph?

Compare the two graphs by eyeball a few times, and be happy now that we did not straighten out the dogleg. :-)

The thing here is that we have *not* added any commits, so there are no commits we would have to *remove* either, even if you have pushed this.  The only thing a successful `git push` would do is to convince the receiving repository's git to move its `master` branch to point to the same node as `dev2`.

#### Assuming the above is all accurate (or close enough): what happens if we rewind and make a true merge?

First, let's simulate `git reset --hard <commit-id>` by yanking the `master` label back up to the top, giving us the first graph again:

```
... - o - o           <-- HEAD->master
           \
            o - o     <-- dev1
                 \
                  o   <-- dev2
```

Now let's do a `git merge --no-ff dev1` to make a real, actual merge node.  Again, draw the graph:

```
... - o - o ----- o   <-- HEAD->master
           \     /
            o - o     <-- dev1
                 \
                  o   <-- dev2
```

And now let's make another real merge, `git merge --no-ff dev2` (the `--no-ff` is not actually required this time but let's use it for consistency and clarity of intent):

```
... - o - o ----- o - o   <-- HEAD->master
           \     /   /
            o - o <-/-------- dev1
                 \ /
                  o       <-- dev2
```

(`dev1` still points the same place; I just started running out of room on the page here, so I tried my best to draw it reasonably clearly.)

If we never pushed the `master` update anywhere, obviously nobody else had any idea we ever did anything and we can push this safely.

#### What if we did push, but otherwise everything drawn so far is close enough?

Suppose we were to `git push` *now*, after the remote already had `master` pointing to the same commit as `dev2`?  There are now two possibilities:

1. `master` there still points to the same commit as `dev2`.  We will be asking the remote to fast-forward the name `master` to point to our second merge commit.  This *is* a fast-forward because our second merge commit has *two* parent commits.  Its first parent is our first merge commit, and its second parent is the commit to which `dev2` points.  The remote will therefore allow this as a regular (non-forced) push!
2. Someone else has added a new commit (or several new commits).  Well, *now* we're in a bit of trouble, because now *we* have to either force-push (dropping their commits and making them re-do work), or we have to discard our merges, pick up their stuff, and re-do our merges, and we get a bit of fluff in our branch and our merge parents are not the way we wanted them and so on.  That is, we'll probably wind up with a graph that looks more like this after the first merge:

   ```
   ... - o - o       ------- o   <-- HEAD->master
              \     /       /
               o - o   <---/-------- dev1
                    \     /
                     o <-/---------- dev2
                      \ /
                       o         <-- origin/master
   ```

   and trying to draw in the second merge is even worse (probably time to scrap this version of the graph and start over :-) ).

#### Bottom line

It depends on the graph.  Draw what you have, draw what you have pushed to others, and draw what you would prefer to have instead.  See if what you would prefer can be pushed without `--force`.